# SQL - Counting references in multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is the scenario.  I have a MySQL table called modules which contains one or more entries each identified by a unique string - the module ID (mid).

There are a few other tables (scripts,images,sets...) which contain objects each of which"belong" to one of the modules - identified by the column 'mid' in each table.

Prior to allowing a user to drop a module entry, I need to check that the operation will not leave any orphaned objects in any of the other tables.  Here is an example to make this clearer

```
Table modules
mname      mid
Mod1      abcd1234
Mod2      wxyz9876

Table scripts
sname     mid 
  A       abcd1234
  B       wxyz9876

Table images
iname   mid
 A      abcd1234

Table  sets
sname    mid
```

One or more of the tables may contain no, or no matching, entries.

I have written and tested a spot of SQL to handle this.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `images` WHERE mid = 'abcd1234'
UNION
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `sets` WHERE mid = 'abcd1234'
UNION
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `scripts` WHERE mid = 'abcd1234'
```

which very obligingly returns **1** implying that the module is "in use" and cannot be dropped.  However, my SQL skills are pretty basic.  I would much appreciate anyone who could tell me if this is a safe way to do things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really a good way.

The `UNION` without `ALL` removes duplicate results. That would give you 1 if you had 3 rows returning 1. `UNION ALL` will make it return 3 rows with the count for each table, even when they are duplicate. After that you `SUM` them and you get the final count.

You should do:

```
SELECT SUM(cnt) FROM (
 SELECT COUNT(*) as cnt FROM `images` WHERE mid = 'abcd1234'
 UNION ALL
 SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `sets` WHERE mid = 'abcd1234'
 UNION ALL
 SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `scripts` WHERE mid = 'abcd1234'
) a
```

Comment: I am afraid, that does not work - SQL complains "Each derived table must have its own alias".  That apart, I don't really care how many module references there are.  I just need to know that the module is in use (0, 1) so I can block its removal

Comment: Yes. sorry. it needs an alias at the end. I'll add it. If you want to validate if you only want to know if it is there or not, this is probably best also, because your query returned 1, but if you remove one of the results from one of the 3 tables, you would get two rows, one with 0 and one with 1.

Comment: Thanks, that works.  However, I do not understand why you have an alias in the first of the selects and then the a at the finish.  I have never used aliases so it does not make sense to me.  Your solution is certainly better since what I require as the result is a number whereas my original SQL would have returned an array of values.

Comment: The first is to name the column that you want to do the SUM. When doing UNION, the first select gives the name to the columns. Then, it is necessary to name every derived table, since you are doing the SUM based on the results of those 3 queries combined, you have to name it also. It ends up doing something like: `SELECT SUM(cnt) FROM a;`, being a the table that results from the UNIONs

Comment: Thanks.  The only thing I would add here - UNION ALL is nice to know the NUMBER of module references but not required otherwise.

Comment: @DroidOS. Yes. It is not required, but If you want to validate only if the value returned is > 0, It's faster to do UNION ALL, since UNION is going to do extra validations to get you only the DISTINCT values.

Answer (score 0):

You could build something around the following concept, given that there is a one-to-many relation between modules and the other tables.

```
select mid
      ,count(scripts.sname) as scripts
      ,count(images.iname)  as images
      ,count(sets.sname)    as sets
  from modules
  left join images   using(mid)
  left join sets     using(mid)
  left join scripts  using(mid) 
 where mid = 'abcd1234'
 group 
    by mid;
```

You could for example add the count(..) together, or including a HAVING clause.